# I cant read a video after write it in the SD

Tags: android, android-video-player

I download a video to my SD Card with this code

```
File SDCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            //create a new file, specifying the path, and the filename
            //which we want to save the file as.
            File file = new File(PATHSdcard,key+".avi");

            //this will be used to write the downloaded data into the file we created
            FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);

            //this will be used in reading the data from the internet
            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            //create a buffer...
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bufferLength = 0; //used to store a temporary size of the buffer

            //now, read through the input buffer and write the contents to the file
            while ( (bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0 ) {
                    //add the data in the buffer to the file in the file output stream (the file on the sd card
                    fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
            }
            //close the output stream when done
            fileOutput.flush();
            fileOutput.close();
```

But when i try to view the video i get a error message.

But if i close the application, disable the debug mode and wait few minutes, i can view the video.
How is the problem?

Thanks

Comment: invoke the media scanner as covered in several existing questions here

Comment: Thanks, it worked!!
I cant view the video when i am in the activity, but when i view with the files explorer i can view instantly